# How do I shatter rigid bodies on edges

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

So, I'm creating a rigid body that I am going to throw and I was wondering, is there any way to make the rigid bodies break apart on impact (Similar to the cell frac add-on) except on the edges?

Comment: You might want to consider ending the bounty as it does not show up in the bountied question section anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of very good fracture add-ons out there. Some of them only support fracturing the *entire* object at one time, while others actually let you control the places that the object fractures. You may want to consider [this](https://blender.community/c/graphicall/Qbbbbc/) add-on as it lets you do that kind of thing with objects. I am positive that there is no way to automatically generate fractured edges based off of the rigid-body simulation, but this add-on should help a lot.

Comment: What about the Explode modifier as used in CG Geek's tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3dTcz5wWvVE&t=104s (Watch from about 14:45 minutes I think

Comment: This add-on improves a lot of that. I.e. makes it simpler.

Comment: Is it available for MACos? I use Mac. It says "Windows" on it.

Comment: Its says windows, but there is a Mac build download link on the page.